# TextArea Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

**I know** that a similar question has already been dealt with on **stackoverflow**. But I could not put together a solution from the proposed one. I am very ashamed.

The essence is this: I have a component and another one inside it.
The child component-**VClipboardTextField** is a ready-made configured **text-area**. I couldn't get the **input** out of there and I don't get an error when I try to enter it.

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
> whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
> computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
> "message"

[image]
code **tabs-item.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row align="center">
      <v-col cols="9">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>
            <h1>Request</h1>
            <v-container>
              <v-textarea v-model="message"
                          placeholder="Placeholder"
                          label="Request"
                          auto-grow
                          clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
                          clearable
                          rows="10"
                          row-height="5"


                          @click:clear="clearMessage"
              ></v-textarea>
              <v-textarea v-model="response"
                          placeholder="Placeholder"
                          label="Request2"
                          auto-grow
                          counter
                          rows="10"
                          row-height="5"
                          color="success"
              ></v-textarea>

              <VClipboardTextField ></VClipboardTextField>
              <VClipboardTextField isReadOnly></VClipboardTextField>
            </v-container>

            <v-row>

              <v-btn
                dark
                color="primary"
                elevation="12"
                justify="end"
                float-right
                @click="sendRequest"
              >
                Send Request
              </v-btn>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>

      <v-col cols="3">
        <schema-selector @changeSchema="onChangeSchema"></schema-selector>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'tabs-item',
  props: ['response'],
  data() {
    return {
      schema: String,
      message: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendRequest() {
      const message = {
        message: this.message,
        method: this.schema.state
      }
      this.$emit('sendRequest', message)
    },
    clearMessage() {
      this.message = ''
    },
    onChangeSchema(selectS) {
      console.log("get schema: ", selectS.state)
      this.schema = selectS

    }
  },

}
</script>
```

and child **VClipboardTextField.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-tooltip bottom
               v-model="show">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-textarea
          v-model="message"
          :append-outer-icon="'mdi-content-copy'"
          :readonly="isReadOnly"
          auto-grow
          filled
          counter
          clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
          clearable
          label="Response message"
          type="text"
          @click:append-outer="copyToBuffer"
          @click:clear="clearMessage"
        ></v-textarea>

      </template>
      <span>Tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VClipboardTextField',
  props: {
    isReadOnly: Boolean,
    message : { type :String, default: "msg"}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    //  messageLocal: 'Response!',
      iconIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    copyToBuffer() {
      console.log("this: ", this)
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.message);
      this.toolTipChange()
      setTimeout(() => this.toolTipChange(), 1000)
    },
    clearMessage() {
      this.message = ''
    },
    toolTipChange() {
      if (this.show)
        this.show = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I will be glad to see an example of the code that will explain how to correctly solve this problem without crutches!
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot modify props in components, if the initial value of **message** is needed as placeholder (meaning the input might not be empty at the begining), you can store the data in `message` prop to another data variable and use that as `v-model` to the `textarea`.
if there is no initial value for **message**, just use another data variable for textarea and emit an update for **message** in a **watcher**.

in **code tabs-item.vue**

```
<VClipboardTextField :message.sync="message"></VClipboardTextField>
```

and child **VClipboardTextField.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-tooltip bottom
               v-model="show">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-textarea
          v-model="message_slug"
          :append-outer-icon="'mdi-content-copy'"
          :readonly="isReadOnly"
          auto-grow
          filled
          counter
          clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
          clearable
          label="Response message"
          type="text"
          @click:append-outer="copyToBuffer"
          @click:clear="clearMessage"
        ></v-textarea>

      </template>
      <span>Tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VClipboardTextField',
  props: {
    isReadOnly: Boolean,
    message : { type :String, default: "msg"}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    //  messageLocal: 'Response!',
      iconIndex: 0,
      message_slug: '',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    message_slug(x) {
      this.$emit('update:message', x)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

It will bind the value to `message_slug` and update the `message` on parent component when it's value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **watching for change every time**, you can only emit when there are **changes**.

In your **tabs-item.vue**

```
<VClipboardTextField v-model="message"></VClipboardTextField>
```

In your **VClipboardTextField.vue** component, you can receive the **v-model** input prop as a "**VALUE**" prop and assign it to a local data property. That way u can manipulate the local property and emit only when in it is changed!

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-tooltip bottom v-model="show">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-textarea
          v-model="message"
          :append-outer-icon="'mdi-content-copy'"
          :readonly="isReadOnly"
          v-on="on"
          v-bind="attrs"
          auto-grow
          filled
          counter
          clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
          clearable
          label="Response message"
          type="text"
          @click:append-outer="copyToBuffer"
          @click:clear="clearMessage"
          @change="$emit('input', v)"
        ></v-textarea>
      </template>
      <span>Tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "VClipboardTextField",
  props: {
    isReadOnly: { type: Boolean },
    value: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      message: this.value,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```